# sumlist by divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

i want use divide and conquer algorithm for sum but when i run my code i get the below message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "***.py", line 8, in
>
> print(Sumlist([10,80,30,60,120,150]))   File "***.py", line 6, in Sumlist
> return Sumlist(thelist[:mid])+Sumlist(thelist[mid:])   File "***.py", line 6, in Sumlist
> return Sumlist(thelist[:mid])+Sumlist(thelist[mid:])   File "***.py", line 6, in Sumlist
> return Sumlist(thelist[:mid])+Sumlist(thelist[mid:])   [Previous line repeated 995 more times]   File "***.py", line 2, in Sumlist
> if thelist==[]: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

```
def Sumlist(thelist):
    if thelist==[]:
        return 0
    else:
        mid=len(thelist)//2
        return Sumlist(thelist[:mid])+Sumlist(thelist[mid:])
print(Sumlist([10,80,30,60,120,150]))
```

Comment: Either stack to small or you run in a not ending recursion. Debugging will tell you what it is.

Comment: Instead of checking length of list as a base case , check if mid == 0, like this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128863/1780667

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is getting into infinite recursion because there is no base case for when there is 1 element in the list.

For `len(thelist) == 1`, it infinitely divides into 2 lists of lengths 0 and 1.

Following code should work:

```
def Sumlist(thelist):
    if not thelist:
        return 0
    if len(thelist) == 1:
        return thelist[0]
    
    mid=len(thelist)//2
    return Sumlist(thelist[:mid]) + Sumlist(thelist[mid:])
        
print(Sumlist([10,80,30,60,120,150]))
```

Comment: ```if not thelist:``` is more pythonic

Comment: I disagree that `if not thelist:` is "more pythonic". Here you have two conditions: `len(thelist) == 0` and `len(thelist)==1`. By using `not thelist` instead of `len(thelist) == 0`, you're making a stronger distinction between the len==0 and the len==1 cases, and that's not making the code any easier to read. having the two conditions `len(thelist) == 0` and `len(thelist) == 1` in parallel makes it more obvious at a glance that there is a parallel between the two conditions

Comment: Also another alternative is `if len(thelist) < 2: return next(iter(thelist), 0)` which handles both cases at once. It's shorter (but not necessarily better).

Comment: The alternate solution without considering the length of the list could be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128863/1780667

Answer (score 0):

The base case can also check if "mid == 0" and terminate the recursive calls. The code could be;

```
def sum_list(the_list):
    if  the_list == []:
        return 0
    mid = int(len(the_list) / 2)
    if  mid == 0:
        return the_list[mid]
    else:
        return sum_list(the_list[:mid]) + sum_list(the_list[mid:])
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case if input is empty list. But yes, a nice suggestion.

Comment: @vish4071 thanks for the suggestion , will make an edit after considering that case in code.